# Const objects not in rdata/rodata section

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I can't force msvc10 to put my const object into .rdata section. It always ends up in .data, perfectly initialised (means there is no dynamic initialisation/runtime constructor execution). (compiled with standard project settings of 'release' build).
I dont understand why the  following code can't put 'obj1' into .rdata PE section:

```
typedef struct _Struct1 {
  int m1;
  _Struct1(int p1): m1(p1) {};
  _Struct1() {};
} Struct1;

class Class1 {
public:
  Class1() {};
  Class1(int p1, int p2): m1(p1), m2_struct(p2) {};
  int m1;
  Struct1 m2_struct;
};

const Class1 obj1(1, 2);

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Why obj1 is not going to rdata (checked in IDA) and how to force it in current situation? Tnx.

Comment: Why do you care? Do you have any pressing reason to force it to go to rdata?

Comment: Well, it is an object that won't be changed, rdata is precisely for read-only data. I could say - because I want it there (and imo should be there). Small practical reason is that it shows that compiler perfectly understands, that this object/variable can't be an issue in any race conditions in multithread app (whether or not it is possible, is another issue). Still I wonder what I am doing wrong, or why the compiler is not so eager to use .rdata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These objects have nontrivial constructors, so they have to be initialized dynamically rather than statically. Because of that, they're in the `.data` section (where all dynamically initialized objects lie, as their memory need to be mutated during initialization), even though the compiler was able to optimize out the constructor call in this case.

Actually, nothing prevents the compiler from using `.rdata` in this case. It's just that its developers didn't implement this.

Comment: Line from IDA: .data:00403018 obj1            Class1 <1, <2>>
Compiler was able to figure out the content of the object precisely. No dynamic initialisation takes place. Are you suggesting, that it's simply the way msvc10 treats the case - missed potential 'optimisation'/didn't care about switching PE section assignments at this point?

Comment: Dynamic initialization takes place according to the *standard*. It has been optimized, that's true, but it's still there (in theory at least). Yeah, that's just a missed optimization, I guess.

Comment: Yes the compiler could have put it into .rdata. That can be derived from the C++03 standard, 7.1.5.1 item 4 "Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior."